# possible linux virus file

Tags: linux, virus

I found a file of unknown origin on a server called /var/tmp/f01bdc03.  It was entered in root crontab to run every 10 minutes.  So I made a VM and ran the program with strace.  The only outside connection it made was to 137.74.146.42 which one IP site said was in Hanoi.  Anyway, the messages the mystery program sent to Hanoi are like:

```
NICK RT-WEBM-x86_64-e138231a-XRBRTQ\n
USER Linux localhost localhost :localhost.localdomain 3.10.0-514.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Tue Nov 22 16:42:41 UTC 2016

NOTICE AUTH :*** Looking up your hostname...

:th0m.production.net 001 RT-WEBM-x86_64-e138231a-XRBRTQ 
:this is th0m.production.net you are RT-WEBM-x86_64-e138231a-XRBRTQ!
Linux@<<reversed-lookup-name-for-my-outside-address>>\r\n
:th0m.production.net 005 RT-WEBM-x86_64-e138231a-XRBRTQ CHANTYPES=&# EXCEPT

MODE RT-WEBM-x86_64-e138231a-XRBRTQ -xi\n

JOIN #TM :bleh\n

:th0m.production.net NOTICE RT-WEBM-x86_64-e138231a-XRBRTQ :Setting/removing of usermode(s) 'x' has been disabled.\r\n
```

Does this look familiar to anyone?

Comment: You might want to contact some professionals sooner than later, depending on how valuable the target is.

Comment: the 137.74.146.42 comes from the mystery file doing a DNS lookup of wwww.omfg.pw which is registered by namecheap.com and namecheap doesn't show who has omfg.pw registered

Comment: I think it came from this:  https://www.rapid7.com/db/vulnerabilities/http-webmin-miniserv-format-string-remote-exec

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's indeed malware. The protocol is IRC, which it's using for its command-and-control.

Comment: Irc? Where is coming IRC here?

Comment: "NOTICE AUTH :*** Looking up your hostname..." => typical message from IRC server. "JOIN #TM :bleh\n"  => IRC command to join a channel.